# static css not loading for spring boot project

Tags: java, css, spring

the problem: as u can see from the image, the browser is unable to load the css files.
I also get this exception in STS console:

[2m2018-02-10 19:00:57.770[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16292[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "cancel" not met for actual request parameters:

```
the code was working fine until I completed the included Controller
```

any one has an idea why this is happening?
 Error from the browser(firefox)

```
][1]
```

!DOCTYPE html>

```
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head lang="en" th:fragment="head">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7 /js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link th:href="@{/css/style2.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <link th:href="@{/css/login.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen" th:href="@{/css/login.css}"/>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

> Controller

```
package com.intelbs.controllers;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.intelbs.dao.Customer;
import com.intelbs.dao.Employee;
import com.intelbs.dao.Expense;
import com.intelbs.dao.Note;
import com.intelbs.services.ExpenseService;

@Controller
public class ExpenseController {

    @Autowired
    private ExpenseService expService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/monthlyExpenses", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listMonthlyExpenses(Model model, String month, String year) {
        model.addAttribute("monthlyExpenses", expService.monthExpense(month, year));
        return "monthlyexpensesform";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="new_expense", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String diplayAddExpenseForm( Model model) {
        System.out.println("inside  display");
        model.addAttribute("expense", new Expense());
        return "addexpenseform";

    }

    @RequestMapping(params= "save", method=  RequestMethod.POST)

    public String processAddExpenseForm(@Valid Expense expense, BindingResult br,
                                        Model model, RedirectAttributes ra) {
        System.out.println("inside processform");
        if(br.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("inside has er");    
            return"addexpenseform";

        }

        model.addAttribute("expense", expense);

        expService.saveExpense(expense);

        ra.addFlashAttribute("expense", expense);

        return "redirect:/customers";
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "cancel",method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String cancelAddExpenseForm() {

        return "redirect:/customers";
    }
}

  [Browser error]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO4l5.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are incorrectly using `param` instead of `value` in `@RequestMapping`.

Actually `param` is used to narrow down the requests that are matched for a URL

See the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--)

> A sequence of "myParam=myValue" style expressions, with a request only
>   mapped if each such parameter is found to have the given value.

Refractor your code like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/new_expense", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String diplayAddExpenseForm( Model model) {
        System.out.println("inside  display");
        model.addAttribute("expense", new Expense());
        return "addexpenseform";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/save", method=  RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processAddExpenseForm(@Valid Expense expense, BindingResult br,
                                        Model model, RedirectAttributes ra) {
        System.out.println("inside processform");
        if(br.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("inside has er");    
            return"addexpenseform";

        }

        model.addAttribute("expense", expense);

        expService.saveExpense(expense);

        ra.addFlashAttribute("expense", expense);

        return "redirect:/customers";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/cancel",method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String cancelAddExpenseForm() {

        return "redirect:/customers";
    }
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Subin, that wat it, really appreciated

Comment: Hi Subin, sorry for late reply, I dont know how to accept since I am new here, will appreciate it if you could tell me how.